LuaLaTeX with polyglossia and biblatex
I have the following minimal file
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=austrian]{german}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
Hier steht Inhalt. Welcher jährlich mehr wird.
\end{document}

which produces the following warnings:
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
Module polyglossia Warning: Language naustrian not found in language.dat.lua on
 input line 580

Package biblatex Warning: No hyphenation patterns for 'naustrian' on input line
 580.

) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
Module polyglossia Warning: Language naustrian not found in language.dat.lua on
 input line 580

Package biblatex Warning: No hyphenation patterns for 'naustrian' on input line
 580.

)
Module polyglossia Warning: Language naustrian not found in language.dat.lua on
 input line 20

Package biblatex Warning: No hyphenation patterns for 'naustrian' on input line
 20.

) 


I am running the versions:

lualatex: This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux)
polyglossia: 2024/07/15 v2.2 (but also tried with 2024/03/07 v2.1)
biblatex: 2024/03/21 3.20 (but also tried with 2023/03/05 3.19)

Do you have any advise, what the problem is?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you stuck with having to use polyglossia, or are you free to switch to babel?

I was thinking that polyglossia is more modern and works better with LuaLaTeX. But I've read some other TeX.SE answers on this topic in the mean time. And get the impression, that babel is working far more better with biblatex. I will give babel a try.

I want to use polyglossia with LuaLaTeX but I am facing with same issues. it seems to me that babel is working better.

I've submitted a bug report to polyglossia. Maybe some help from there.
